# jQueryUI Sortable across multiple models

Tags: jquery, sorting, yii, jquery-ui-sortable

Does anyone know how to sort items across multiple models?

I am building a CMS and I want the user to be able to sort content, however there are many different models for the content types.

eg.
-links
-galleries
-pages
-images

Each model has the column 'sort_order'.

I am trying to do this using Yii, but if you know how to do it in another platform, I should be able to figure it out from there.

Here's how to do it within one model
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/238/creating-a-jqueryui-sortable-cgridview/

Answer (score 1):

I this case a column per model would allow you to only sort models among other models of the same type.

What you need to sort models relative to models of other types, its a general table. where you store for example, the model's id, the model's type, maybe the model's table name, and of course the order. you should also have some kind of grouper, say a layout? a column were you sort widgets/links/etc. in that case you need another table for that

It depends a lot on how are you structuring you CMS. I think its more like an architectural problem rather than "how to sort different models on the same CGridView"

Comment: Thanks @Asgaroth. This helps and puts me looking on the right track. Can anyone point me to an example of how to do this? I would like to know what the best practices are for implementation. Or perhaps even appropriate keywords or terms for searching 'ol google. I'm turning up a little dry on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering this myself. I'm thinking that the sort_order will need to be its own model, in order to have a integer with uniqueness across the desired models.

```
belongs_to :sort_order
```